# I declare a List but hibernate instance a Set

Tags: mongodb, collections, hibernate-ogm

I just found out that when I'm going to store in my mongodb, with hibernate ogm, a list this becomes a set (so no repetitions).
How can I avoid it?
Here's how I declared the field:

```
@ElementCollection private List<Double> doubles;
```

For example,
I have this list: [0.1 0.1 0.1 0.3]
When i'm going to store, it becames [0.1 0.3]

An escamotage would be to define a collection like this:

```
@ElementCollection private Map<Integer,Double> doubles;
```

But this structure is unnecessarily complex and in my case, that I have to put very long vectors, it might be a problem!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify the *type* of the collection that Hibernate will use in the mapping.

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#example.collections.set) - it provides xml mapping samples, quote:

> Apart from the  tag as shown in Example 7.4, “Mapping a Set using
>   ”, there is also list, map, bag, array and
>   primitive-array mapping elements.

Also, check out [Hibernate - Bag Mappings](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_bag_mapping.htm)

For example in *Fluent NHibernate* you can use `.AsBag()` and `.AsSet()` extension methods on a mapping to indicate if you want a bag semantics, i.e. unordered 
 sequence with duplicates.

See [this blog post](http://marekblotny.blogspot.com/2009/02/fluent-nhbernate-and-collections.html) and [this blog post](http://www.jagregory.com/writings/introducing-fluent-nhibernate/) for an example of using this in *NHibernate*

In essence, your fluent mapping could look something like this

```
public YourClassMap : ClassMap<YourClass>
{
  public YourClassMap()
  {
    HasMany<double>(x => x.doubles)
      .AsBag()
      .Access.CamelCaseField();
...
```

Your xml mapping would look something like this

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="YourNamespace" assembly="YourAssembly">
  <class name="YourClass" table="YourTableName">
  ...
    <bag name="doubles" table="Doubles">
      <one-to-many class="Double"/>
    </bag>
```

Sorry for providing examples only for **N**Hibernate, this is what I work with daily, you should be able to fairly easily apply this in Hibernate as well

Comment: Thanks, but I've never mapped an entity with XML. Although I try, I receive an error.
It's a bit contorted though. After all, I ask a little.

Comment: @Daniel-san, could you please provide the error that you're getting? And perhaps the component mapping that you're trying to get to work.

Comment: The error is in Italian but in essence it says that <class> MyClass </ class> does not want attributes. We're talking about dependencies.xml, right?

Comment: @Daniel-san, according to the example below the mapping file should be named <classname>.hbm.xml, see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_bag_mapping.htm